# Unable to launch emulator on Android Studio: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false, then unable to locate adb

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When trying to run my device emulator on Android Studio, a pop-up appears:
[image: popup description]
Previously, I had gotten the error '`Unable to locate adb`', but after replacing the default `platform_tools` folder with the
[official version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools), this pop-up now replaced the last one. I don't think this is a problem with my installation, as I've uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and the flutter-sdk several times, each attempt met with the `unable to locate adb` error, then this one. Could it be the way I'm unzipping a certain file? I'm grasping at straws here.
Are there any fixes for this? To be honest, I'm not even sure where to start. I haven't seen any other page that describes getting this error while trying to launch an emulator.

Thank you for your time!

Edit: Error description in plain-text:

```
EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@2c5cc720
Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 4,4,Idea Thread Group] 1175604479
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,Idea Thread Group] 1657237134
```

I've tried to create a new device and wipe the data on my current one, but that just results in the `unable to locate adb` pop-up again (I don't have an antivirus like Avaast enabled by the way), and I am absolutely certain that adb.exe is in my file-path (`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`). I have uninstalled and reinstalled platform-tools from the SDK-manager multiple times, each instance being met with this same error. I cannot run any flutter program, on any emulator. I have not yet tried with a regular Android Studio project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, i'm still not sure why the EventQueue error is showing, but what I do know is that the `unable to locate adb` is a negligible pop-up if you know for certain that `adb.exe` is in your file-directory. My issue was that I didn't have enough memory to run the emulator on my machine, so be sure to have plenty of room while developing apps (~11 gigs while using Android Studio and flutter-sdk)! That's all, it certainly was a strange experience working through it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what helped, was to just restart an emulator.